# .Net c# libraries / assemblies - Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

i've developed a .Net C# (Crystal Reports) application in computer 1

dependencies link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEsb8.png

while running this application in computer 2 , it doesn't work because of the missing dependencies

how can i import all these dependencies with the application to make it running everywhere ?

not by copy & paste all the Needed DLLs in the same path with the executable ?
or how ?

thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the **Crystal reports** on the target machine. By this you will have all `dll`s on the same path and application will find them automatically.

Comment: i thought that importing some DLLs will be sufficient ... it was not, because the applications needs other assemblies ..

Precisely, CRRedist2005_x86.msi to install the needed Assemblies , that works well for me , thanx